# Is there a word for "a name you legally gave yourself"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, names

Let's say that there's a woman known since birth as Alice Smith who later changes her name to Mary Jones.  'Alice Smith' would be her "birthname"; is there a word for Mary Jones meaning "a name she gave herself"?

I see that there's a word "[autonym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autonym)," which would *seem* to be what I'm looking for, but it does not appear to actually have that meaning.

Note that I'm not looking for the term "married name," which would apply to a name acquired through marriage.

It could of course be the case that a person legally changes just their first name (not a nickname but a completely different name), but keeps the last name.  What would that first name be called?

UPDATE: Lots of good answers here, getting at various nuances.  In the particular case, I am asking about, the name was legally changed, so many of the answers (like "pseudonym") probably wouldn't work.  Sorry I wasn't clearer when I said that she "changes her name."

Comment: I don't know whether there's an official term for this, but for a new **first name** it would be understandable if you referred to it as a _chosen name_, to contrast it with one's original (birth) name, which is also called  _given name_.

Comment: Ah, interesting -- I hadn't thought of "chosen name."  Does that connote, though, that the name is not the person's real name?  If there is no such connotation, this would probably be the best answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "real name"—the one they were born with? I don't see how one could confuse that with a _chosen_  name.

Comment: This [document from ASU](https://www.registrar.arizona.edu/sites/default/files/Preferred-Chosen%20Name%20Guidelines%20v2.pdf), for example, pretty clearly distinguishes between a person's "chosen name" and their "official/legal name."

Comment: I see. So they treat it as an "I would rather be called", as distinguished from legal name.  So "chosen" doesn't fulfill your requirement.

Comment: If the name was legally changed, and the person is being referred to using that new name, it is their *legal name*.

Comment: Yes, but that is also true of those who have never changed their names at all.  I was looking for a word or term that captures the notion that the name was chosen by the bearer, that it is not their given name. "Legally assumed name" fits the bill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going with "legally assumed name," because

- It *does* imply that the name has been changed.
- It does *not* imply that the name is not a true, legal name.
- It does *not* have an implied context, e.g. war, theater, authorship, or crime.

Thanks to Mazura for the hint, which led me to this in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_name):

> Most state courts have held that a legally assumed name (i.e., for a
>   non-fraudulent purpose) is a legal name and usable as their true name,
>   ...

although it does go on to add this:

> ... though assumed names are often not considered the person's
>   technically true name.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your use of the term "legally".  Normally the term "legal name", when applied to a name that is not the birth name or "married name", means that the individual has petitioned a court to change the name.  There are other cases where a person may "legally" use a different name, but that does not make the name a "legal name" in the usual sense of the term.

Comment: Perhaps you are not confused after all, because in fact in this case the individual has indeed petitioned a court to change the name.  That's why I am using the terms "legal" and "legally" (although it is my understanding that a court order is not a requirement for a name change to be legal).

Answer (score 6):

If the person writes under a "false name" then **pseudonym** is the answer.

If the person has chosen to call him or herself with one name only, such as *Adele*, *Prince*, Pelé or *Sting*, then the term is  **mononym**. For example, “Her mononym is Shakira.”

> [A single name by which a person, thing etc is known. For example, *Madonna* (the pop musical artist)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mononym)

Talking of Prince, when he changed his name to the so-called ‘love’ symbol [image], for a number of years he was known as  "The Artist Formerly Known as Prince", "TAFKAP", or just "The Artist". Likewise anyone could **rename** him or herself and say:

> I'm [new first name], ***formerly known as*** [old first name].
>   OR
>   I'm [new first name], but I used to be called [old first name].

If a person dislikes their first name (for whatever reason), they can just call themselves with a different name. Sometimes a family *nickname* sticks, and that person grows up with that name. Changing a name by [deed poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deed_poll) might include a lengthy  process depending on one's nationality.

> The most common use is a name change through a deed of change of name (often referred to simply as a deed poll). Deeds poll are used for this purpose in countries including the United Kingdom, Ireland, New Zealand, Hong Kong and Singapore. **In the UK, a deed poll can also be used to change a child's name**, as long as everyone with parental responsibility for the child consents to it and the child does not object to it. The child's parents execute the deed poll on the child's behalf. **In some other jurisdictions, a person may simply start using a new name without any formal legal process**.
>
> Wikipedia

Oxford Dictionaries:

> **[pseudonym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pseudonym)**
>   (noun)
>   a fictitious name, especially one used by an author.
>   "I wrote under the pseudonym of Evelyn Hervey"
>
> **synonyms**: *pen name*, *assumed name*, *alias*, *professional name*, *sobriquet*, *stage name*, *nickname*

Answer (score 5):

[Alias](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alias) is the name that you use in addition to your *real name*. It doesn't have a connotation of *self-given*, but it doesn't have a connotation of *others-given*, either.

> an additional name that a person (such as a criminal) sometimes uses.

[Merriam-Webster]

"Self-given alias" will be much clearer in your context.

Answer (score 3):

Consider, **moniker**.

> : a name, title or alias [Computer Desktop Encyclopedia](http://www.yourdictionary.com/moniker)
>
> *He gave himself the moniker of Drew Danburry, hit the road with his guitar and never looked back* [Kuer](http://kuer.org/post/understanding-drew-drew-danburry-reveals-his-creative-inspiration-making-music)
>
> **Everyone knew her as Nancy**.
>
> Dear Word Detective: I have often been puzzled by the derivation of
> the word "Monica" or "Moniker" when used in the context "Can you
> please stick your moniker on here," meaning "can you please sign this"
> or "can you please put your signature on here." In the past I have
> been told that it was possibly used in a kind of coded slang used by
> Irish Americans. But even if that were true, it still doesn't explain
> the derivation. I would have thought it much more likely to be cockney
> rhyming slang -- I'd love to bet there was a famous socialite called
> Monica Rignature or something ("Rignature - Signature"). Ha Ha! --
> Adam Archer.
>
> Well, that's not absolutely impossible, since a couple of the theories
> that are considered possible explanations for "moniker" (as it is
> usually spelled) are nearly as odd. That's a sort of backhanded way of
> admitting that no one knows exactly where "moniker," **meaning "a name,
> especially an assumed one,"** or "a nickname," came from, but at least
> we have some entertaining possibilities to poke at.
>
> "Moniker" first appeared as slang around 1851 in several different
> spellings, including "monaker," "monarch," "monekur," "monikey,"
> "monnick," and "monniker." By the 20th century, the spelling "moniker"
> seems to have largely won out, although the variant "monica" is cited
> in the Oxford English Dictionary from 1968.
>
> The pioneering etymologist Eric Partridge favored the notion that
> "moniker" is related to "monarch," in the sense of "king," in that
> one's name "partly rules" one's life. Frankly, this seems a bit of a
> stretch to me (and rather literary for what was, after all, originally
> street slang).
>
> Another interesting theory explains "moniker" as originating in
> "back-slang" (a reverse slang common in Britain) for "ekename."
> "Ekename" was the original form of our modern word "nickname," "eke"
> being an old English word meaning "additional." (Through a process
> called "metanalysis," the "n" in "an" in the phrase "an ekename"
> drifted over and gave us "a nickname." The same process transformed "a
> napron" into "an apron.")
>
> Anyway, the reverse slang for "ekename" would be "emaneke," which
> gradually mutated, according to this theory, to "moneker" and so on.
> Again, this is far from impossible, but seems a bit too elaborate.
>
> Perhaps the simplest theory (and I like simple theories) is that
> "moniker" is just a blending, perhaps originally jocular, of
> "monogram" and "signature." [The Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/042805.html)

Answer (score 3):

Their new title is the product of a [name change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_change), for which Wikipedia uses the word *adopted* a lot.

Informal methods of a name change include *assumed* names and *common law* names. Once all the paperwork clears, it will become their *legal* name which would then be different from their *given* name.

> A person's first [**legal name**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_name) generally is the name of the person that was given for the purpose of registration of the birth and which then appears on a birth certificate (see birth name), **but may change subsequently**.

<sub>This is an American's view point; we don't have 'deed polls'.</sub>

---

Edit:

The OP favored **assumed name** for their purposes. E.g.:

> They fled their oppressive life in the city, took an *assumed name* and began their life anew.

Comment: @AmigoNico Ultimately I'm suggesting *legal name*, but it depends how far you've pushed the paperwork. You might be 'legally' living under an assumed name (through common law in some areas) but until you sign up at the DMV in my area, it's unofficial.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider *nom-de-guerre*

It may not technically *be* English, but it's used often, and has been more-or-less adopted, just like many other words of foreign origin.

(See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym#Noms_de_guerre), from Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

**Nom de Jure**-- French borrowed term, De Jure is used to form compound terms. It means 'based on or according to law' (Merriam-Webster.com) Examples include nom de Guerre (Patton: Óld Blood 'n Guts', Nom de Plume (Compte St. Charles Armand Gabriel de Gramont: Ted Morgan).

Answer (score -1):

a **self-given nickname** or the **name she gave herself** would suffice.